# Jenkins - How to access BUILD_NUMBER environment variable

Tags: jenkins

Are *Jenkins* parameters case-sensitive? I have a parametrized build which needs an *ant* parameter named `"build_parameter"` to be set before the build. When I try to access the `${BUILD_NUMBER}` set by *Jenkins*, I get the value set for the ant parameter. If the build parameters are not case sensitive, can anyone suggest me a work around to this issue? I cannot change the build parameter name as I will have to change my build scripts (which is not an option). Thanks!

Comment: Refer https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-1322

Comment: Adarsh: My build_parameter and environment variable ${BUILD_NUMBER} have different values. Sorry for not being clear. I need a way to access the Jenkins ${BUILD_NUMBER} value. However, when I try to access it the way we do for environmental variables (${BUILD_NUMBER}) it prints out the other value.

Comment: According to my investigation BUILD_NUMBER gives you current build number. So you need to change your build script. Or try creating new variable and assign it value of BUILD_NUMBER and using it.

Comment: Refer https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables for variables

Comment: I can't seem to memorize the var names, so I often refer to  http://localhost:8080/env-vars.html

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To Answer your first question, Jenkins variables are case sensitive. However, if you are writing a windows batch script, they are case insensitive, because Windows doesn't care about the case.

Since you are not very clear about your setup, let's make the assumption that you are using an ant build step to fire up your ant task. Have a look at [the Jenkins documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-AntScripts) (same page that Adarsh gave you, but different chapter) for an example on how to make Jenkins variables available to your ant task.

**EDIT:**

> Hence, I will need to access the environmental variable ${BUILD_NUMBER} to construct the URL.

Why don't you use `$BUILD_URL` then? Isn't it available in the extended email plugin?

Comment: Peter: Please refer to my comment above for Sagar's response. I need to get the value of the environmental variable ${BUILD_NUMBER}, however I suppose it is getting overwritten by the other parameter (lower case parameter). I am using Mac OS and I am not using these params in any bash script. All I am trying to do is to use it in the Extended Email Notification email content.

Comment: Peter: Thanks for your suggestion. I did try out ${BUILD_URL} after you had suggested. It does take me to the build page. Is there a way to point it directly to the artifact so that it will start the download of the artifact directly from the link in the email?

Comment: It's ${BUILD_URL}/artifact/<path_to_artifact>

Comment: I'm surprised that this is the accepted answer, because the question doesn't say anything about Windows. I don't know of any other OS where environment variables are case-insensitive, and it's definitely not good practice to assume case insensitivity. (I've worked on a lot of projects where developers using Windows are responsible for making sure their commits don't break normal operating systems, especially filenames. Thankfully, case-insensitive filenames can apparently be turned off in Windows, and this is considered best practice.)

Answer (score 14):

Assuming I am understanding your question and setup correctly,

If you're trying to use the build number in your script, you have two options:

1) When calling ant, use: `ant -Dbuild_parameter=${BUILD_NUMBER}`

2) Change your script so that:

```
<property environment="env" />
<property name="build_parameter"  value="${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"/>
```

Comment: Sagar: I use parameterized build option to make the user enter the build_number parameter (note: it is in lower_case) and then use it in my ant script. However, I need to send out an email with the artifact location as a URL. Hence, I will need to access the environmental variable ${BUILD_NUMBER} to construct the URL. Now, the user entered parameter ${build_number} and the environmental variable ${BUILD_NUMBER} are different. But if I append ${BUILD_NUMBER} to the URL, it always takes up the value stored in ${build_number}.

Comment: Aah ok. In that case, why don't you change "build_number" to "build.number" in your parameter list. It still has the same meaning, and people won't confuse it with anything else; at the same time, it will be different from BUILD_NUMBER completely. I'm not sure there is case insensivity (are either your server or your client on Windows?), but that would be your best way out. You can still use point 1 or 2 above to match your script's internal variables to the parameter and environment variables.

Answer (score 8):

For Groovy script in the Jenkinsfile using the **$BUILD_NUMBER** it works.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$env:BUILD_NUMBER` in PowerShell script