# Jenkins REST API: get a build number of a job that just started

Tags: jenkins

I'm starting the job by issuing this request

```
/POST /jenkins/job/jobName/build
```

but it returns nothing. I want to get the build number that just has started.

Answer (score 1):

Although late , posting an answer so it can benefit any other seekers :

We can get the latest/current build no. using the following API :

```
<JENKINS_URI>/job/<JOB_NAME>/lastBuild/buildNumber
```

This will provide the current executing or the last successful build.

Example :

```
curl -X GET <JENKINS_URI>/<JOB_NAME>/lastBuild/buildNumber --user <user>:<key>
o/p : 20
```

Comment: I dont think this is a good solution because, if someone else has also triggered the job, you will end up monitoring the wrong job

Comment: I agree with @anandhu

Answer (score 1):

This is how i do it, First trigger the Job with the rest api call. From this call's response, get the queue location. And using this queue location, fetch the build number. The build number will not be generated immediately, thats why the while loop.

```
JENKINS_EMAIL=<Email>
JENKINS_TOKEN=<API Key>
JENKINS_URL=<Jenkins Server URL>
JENKINS_JOB=<JOB>
        
# Trigger Job and get queue location

location=$(curl -X POST -s -I -u $JENKINS_EMAIL:$JENKINS_TOKEN "${JENKINS_URL}${JENKINS_JOB}/buildWithParameters?pass=ok" | grep location | awk '{ print $NF }')
location2=${location//[$'\t\r\n']}

# Wait till build number is generated

while true ; do
    
    buildnumber=$(curl -X GET -s -u $JENKINS_EMAIL:$JENKINS_TOKEN "${location2}api/json" | jq '.executable.number')

    if [[ $buildnumber != "null" ]]; then
        echo "Build Started. Build number is : "$buildnumber"
        break
    else
        echo "Still in Queue"
        sleep 1
    fi  
done
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @user1745356 please mark this as solution

Answer (score -2):

[Jenkins - How to access BUILD_NUMBER environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179447/jenkins-how-to-access-build-number-environment-variable)

use ${BUILD_NUMBER} to get the current build.

already extensive answers are available in stack overflow. kindly surf it before raising the question.

Comment: Before answering a question please read it more carefully. This is not what I need.

Comment: cool.. have you gone through curl commands??  you should provide complete URL and also U have to  use API variables to get the build details. edit your question with more clarity