# How to get the right build number for a build triggered in Jenkins by remote API

Tags: python, api, jenkins

I am triggering builds with parameters in Jenkins using Python request to the http://jenkins:8080/view/projectAlpha/job/deploy_job_with_params/build and I don't get any queue or build numbers to identify my build.

According to Jenkins' /api page for the above url:

> "To programmatically schedule a new build, post to this URL (means the /build url - RaamEEIL). If the
>   build has parameters, post to this URL (means the /buildWithParameters url - RaamEEIL) and provide the parameters as
>   form data. Either way, the successful queueing will result in 201
>   status code with Location HTTP header pointing the URL of the item in
>   the queue."

However, instead of getting the queue's url (e.g. http://jenkins:8080/queue/item/21038/api/json) in the location header that returns when depploying the build, I get the url http://jenkins:8080/view/projectAlpha/job/deploy_job_with_params/ so basically I don't get any queue number or build number

I read a suggestion for a workaround, to send an additional parameter with some id, which I can use to verify that the latest build is my build or use it to search through a list of builds until I find the correct build.

Thanks.

Comment: I have posted my solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29150106/jenkins-rest-api-get-a-build-number-of-a-job-that-just-started/74162441#74162441

Answer (score 2):

Well, it turns out that I got things mixed up. This seems to happen to many others, so here is some info.

/build url - returns **location = the url of the job. doesn't include info on your build**

/buildWithParameters url - returns **location = the url of the queue item for your build**

According to Daniel Beck's comment on https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-30317 -

(By "This" the author means the /build url)

> That's the problem. This is not actually the API. As I wrote before,
>   the API as documented uses /buildWithParameters for parameterized
>   builds. This is pretending to be a web browser.
>
> ...because web browsers would get redirected
>   to a blank 404 error page. Again, you're not actually using the API
>   here, you're pretending to be a web browser.

So, although the API page states you can request the /build url, if you want to get the queue item url for your build as the 'location' header, you must request the /buildWithParameters url.