# How to build Jenkins job through command line by passing password parameter

Tags: jenkins, terminal, jenkins-cli

I need to invoke a jenkins job via mac terminal using jenkins cli.

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s <jenkin_server> -auth username:token build myjobname -s -v -p param1=hello
```

This works perfectly

However, in the job if param1 is a password parameter, I am getting below error:

```
ERROR: CLI parameter submission is not supported for the class com.michelin.cio.hudson.plugins.passwordparam.PasswordParameterDefinition type. Please file a bug report for this
```

How do I invoke a jenkins job using cli, passing password parameters?
I see this issue being reported here but no solutions yet - https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-55925

If this is not possible, is there any other workaround?

Comment: How about using the Rest API instead?

Comment: The problem with rest API is ,  I cannot stream the build logs into my console. I can just trigger the job and thats it. Also, are you aware if its possible to stream the logs itself using jenkins cli if i have the build number i triggered using jenkins Rest API? I couldnt find any documentation

Comment: Never mind. I did it wit rest API Solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29150106/jenkins-rest-api-get-a-build-number-of-a-job-that-just-started/74162441#74162441