# Jenkins - Publish HTML report to custom URL

Tags: html, jenkins, reporting

One of my jobs in Jenkins generates an html report and uses the [HTML Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin) to link to it from respective build. In such case, if I want to get to this HTML page directly (*assume no security enabled so no log in required*), I need to follow a link that has the following form:

http://hostname:port/job/Some%20Job%20Name/buildNumber/Functional_Test_Report/

And for each subsequent build, the URL is going to change based on `buildNumber`. I would like to have a "pretty" URL that will just display the last report all the time. Say something like this:

http://hostname:port/testReport

The actual report HTML will then be automatically pushed into this location every time the build is finished and will eliminate the need of going through Jenkins each time to see the report.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to expose the [BUILD_NUMBER via environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179447/jenkins-how-to-access-build-number-environment-variable) and from there generate the URL where the HTML report will be. How you wanna do it is up to you but you could make it so the Jenkins job either deploys a file that has the build number hard coded in an `index.html` file with a `<script>` that redirects to the URL pattern you posted above. It really depends on how you have your `hostname:port` set up. Since you only need the latest report, you can simply make it so the latest job always overwrites the old file.

We do something similar although we just expose the build number to a PHP, JSP, etc file so QA knows what build they are looking at. We then have a fixed URL they can always go to (`hostname:port/status`). We could make it redirect if we really wanted though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, fixed URL is exactly what I want. Build number should not be a part of the URL and only the last one should be relevant. I am not sure I understand how can I generate such URL as you suggested? And how do I push the report to it? I assume it is some folder that will contain the index.html file?

Comment: This really depends on how you configured your jenkins job but we literally just run a shell script via jenkins to create the file (in the shell script we literally just call `cat`) and then depending where you are hosting your site, we have our jenkins job do a deploy and run the shell script so it will create our web page with the "dynamic" link.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting my own solution here. Perhaps not the most elegant but one way to do it is by deploying an HTTP server on the same machine where Jenkins runs and add a "post build step" in relevant Jenkins job to copy the HTML report files to HTTP server overwriting the existing files if there are any. Then, the report will be available on whatever port the HTTP server is running on.